# Let freezed use factory on initializing

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

I have a freezed class

```
@freezed
class Lobby with _$Lobby implements DataObject {
  @JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, explicitToJson: true)
  const factory Lobby({
    Redirect? redirect,
  }) = _Lobby;
  const Lobby._();

  factory Lobby.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LobbyFromJson(json);
}
```

and an enum

```
enum Redirect {
  test1('/thisistest1'),
  test2('/thisistest2'),

  const Redirect(this.path);

  factory Redirect.fromPath(String path) {
    return values.firstWhere((e) => e.path == path);
  }

  final String path;
}
```

When constructing my `Lobby`-Class I use the `fromJson` factory. In my Json I have the `path` and not the Redirect enum so I need to translate that.

Can I either tell freezed to use the `Redirect.fromPath` factory or can I somehow change the `.fromJson` accordingly?

What would be the best approach?

**EDIT**
I have this data json in my edge-case, this is the print

{redirect: null}

And I am calling `Lobby.fromJson(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try JsonConverter:

```
enum Redirect {
  test1('/thisistest1'),
  test2('/thisistest2');

  const Redirect(this.path);

  factory Redirect.fromPath(String path) => values.firstWhere((e) => e.path == path);

  final String path;
}

class RedirectStringToEnumConvertor implements JsonConverter<Redirect?, String?> {
  const RedirectStringToEnumConvertor();

  @override
  Redirect? fromJson(String? json) => json == null? null : Redirect.fromPath(json);

  @override
  String? toJson(Redirect? object) => object?.toString();
}

@freezed
@JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, explicitToJson: true)
class Lobby with _$Lobby implements DataObject {
  const factory Lobby({
    @RedirectStringToEnumConvertor() Redirect? redirect,
  }) = _Lobby;

  const Lobby._();

  factory Lobby.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LobbyFromJson(json);
}
```

More info [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I get `Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'` though. I changed your method to take `String?`and `Redirect?` but this did not change anything for this error.

Comment: ok, maybe you received {'redirect': null} in response? then to handle this case you will need a little modification. answer updated.

Comment: yes I did exactly that already. Only also using `Redirect?` so it is still a valid override. But I still get the same error. I am a bit puzzled

Comment: when exactly it gives you an error? when app is running? could you add json response to your question?

Comment: When calling `Lobby.fromJson` the error occurs. I edited my question with the json I use to call `fromJson`.

Comment: nevermind. It works. I had a mistake somwhere else. Sorry!